remap vim keybinding
Writing LaTeX in evil, I’d like to remap :w (the usual write command in vim) to TeX-command-run-all, which writes and compiles.
How can this be accomplished?

You don't have to remap. You can add a hook function (function that will be executed after you save the file.)
For example, below I hooked lambda (lambda () (TeX-command-run-all nil)) with after-save-hook. After this, TeX-command-run-all will be executed each time you saved the file, regardless whether you have evil turned on or not.
;; This function will be executed only when you enter LaTeX file
(defun my/set-aftersavehook-when-you-visit-latex-file ()
  ;; setting up the after-save-hook,  after executing this line,
  ;; everytime you save file, TeX-command-run-all will be executed ;
  (add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda () (TeX-command-run-all nil)))
  ;; (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'TeX-command-run-all)  didn't worked because Tex-Command-Run-All requires a argument
  )

;; below is setting up for only for LaTeX-mode.
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my/set-aftersavehook-when-you-visit-latex-file)


I tried this, but this actually does not work here.

You do not need such behavior since this is already implemented in your
doomemacs code - see <localdoomemacsfolder>/modules/lang/latex/config.el,
there is a function +latex/compile () which inside has the expression
(TeX-save-document ...) and is bound to <localleader> a.
